# Detectar ID de un DIV al dar scrolldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo este código:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($('#firstCTA').offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop()){
            //do something
            alert('hey bbay');
        }
        else{
            //do something else
        }
    });
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid" id="firstCTA">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center"> 
                    <img src="assets/imgs/clic-aqui.png" class="arrow-size"> 
                    <h3 class="cta-here-text"><b>Da clic aquí</b></h3>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="firstCTA">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center"> 
                <img src="assets/imgs/clic-aqui.png" class="arrow-size"> 
                <h3 class="cta-here-text"><b>Da clic aquí</b></h3>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quiero detectar el ID de varios DIV, de tal manera que cuando el scroll llegue a #firstCTA, secondCTA y thirdCTA, active una animación. **solo que para probar hice el alert*

Lo que tengo funciona + o menos, ya que antes de pasar el DIV se activa el alert **cada que se hace Scroll Down** y se requiere que se active el alert solo cuando se detecte el ID de los DIV ya mencionados.

Comment: Puedes colocar también el html o parte?

Comment: @ger listo compañero